# GDB print command displaying 12 digit hex value

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb

I have Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox and I am in the terminal trying to debug a program for one of my assignments. When using the print command on an array it gives me a 12 digit hex value like `0x7fffffffdea4`. The code I am debugging is written in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, x[5];
    int *ptr_x;

    cout << "Enter 5 integers";
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        cin >> *ptr_x;
        ptr_x++;
    }
}
```

When I use `print &x[0]`, I would get a 12 digit hex value. I am supposed to use `x/x` to display the contents at the memory address but it says I am unable to access it. Is there a setting I forgot to set because I think I should be getting a 8 digit hex value instead of a 12 digit hex value.

Printing subsequent elements in the array only changes the last 4 digits so I think the first few digits may be filler? What's going on here?

Comment: Because your program is 64-bit, the address is 12 digits. If you want the address is 8 digits, please build it as 32-bit program. BTW, the `ptr_x` is not initialized, are you sure it is right?

Comment: The code was given to me in an assignment and I may have mistyped that. Going back to what you said about building the program as 32-bit. How would I do that?

Comment: call gcc with -m32. 64-bit systems typically have 64-bit pointers which results in 64/4 = 16 hexadecimal digits

Comment: The command I was told to use is `g++ -g arr1_ptr.cc -o arr1`. If I add -m32, is the correct command `g++ -g -m32 arr1_ptr.cc -o arr1`?

Comment: @Skynet: You should try it first.

Comment: I got it to work after installing some gcc lib I found in another thread. Thank you!